# How to rotate UILabel with respect to Top Left corner in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uilabel, cgaffinetransform

I  used the following  code to rotate the label text

```
 mylabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

this will work. But  it will  rotate `UILabel` in Center  .

let say my Top left corner of `UILabel` is (10,10) when i rotate it its Top left corner should not be change(Just like  radius or circle).

How i can rotate it with respect to Top Left corner ?.

please help me

Edit:

here is code

```
  var  transA = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(mylabel.frame.size.width/2,mylabel.frame.size.height/2);
  var  rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4));
  var  transB = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-mylabel.frame.size.width/2,-mylabel.frame.size.height/2);


mylabel.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(transA,rotation),transB);


   var  transform = transA
   mylabel.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(mylabel.transform, transform)
```

EDIT Question :
how to make my Label look like a radius of Circle. i.e. i can rotate it 360 with respect to origin?

Comment: Just quick question for you, so you basically want to rotate your UILabel from the position it is in whilst the top left corner is (10,10) or you want to rotate it so that it stays relative to the top left corner of your display (if you rotate, your top left corner will no longer be the top left corner)

Comment: I want to rotate it so that it stays relative to the top left corner

Comment: Have you made sure that the label has the right constraints? Your code seems to work for me

Comment: Your code looks correct. What happens when you run it?

Comment: it will move but the top left position is change . i want the effect like radius draw from center of circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things you can do about this.

**A)**

You can change the anchor point of the Label:

```
mylabel.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0); // This will set the anchor point to the top left
```

Now you can rotate around this point. This will change the anchor point for ALL transforms!

**B)**

You could do something like this:

```
CGAffineTransform transA = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(mylabel.frame.size.width/2,mylabel.frame.size.height/2);
CGAFfineTransfrom rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
CGAffineTransform transB = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-mylabel.frame.size.width/2,-mylabel.frame.size.height/2);
mylabel.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(transA,rotation),transB);
```

This won't change your anchor point and therefore not impact other transforms!

(If the rotation is wrong, you may have to change `transA` against `transB`)

**UPDATE**

If you want to 'keep' rotation (as asked in the comments), you can just do this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = ... // Put the transform here that you used in A) or B)

mylayer.transfrom = CGAffineTransfromConcat(mylayer.transform,transform);
```

This way you just say 'whereever' I was before - rotate 90 (or 45) degrees more

**UPDATE 2**

Your code should look like this:

```
var  transA = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(mylabel.frame.size.width/2,mylabel.frame.size.height/2);
var  rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2));
var  transB = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-mylabel.frame.size.width/2,-mylabel.frame.size.height/2);


var transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(transA,rotation),transB);

mylabel.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(mylabel.transform, transform)
```

Comment: its work . can u tell how i can achieve rotation like 45, 90. as 45 is work but when i click again it will not become 90

Comment: it will move but the top left position is change . i want the effect like radius draw from center of circle.

Comment: The reason why it's not working is that the frame of the label changes - sry. You should just store the 'number of times' you applied the 45 degree rotation into a variable and then just multiply this value with the M_PI_2

Comment: thanks  for your help. i wait 1-2 day to get good answer if i don't get any answer i will accept your answer